# _startDate Date <unavailable; try printing with "vo" or "po">

Tags: swift

I want to create a date variable but get the following response:

> _startDate    Date    <unavailable; try printing with "vo" or "po">

The code i have is:

```
func createMileagesPDF() {
    var _someDate: NSDate = NSDate()
    
    self.someDate = Date()
    
    guard (!exportYear.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty && exportYear.count == 4) && cars.count > 0 else {
        showAlert.toggle()
        
        return
    }
    
    let _dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    //_dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    
    let _startDateString = String(format: "01-01-%@", exportYear)
    let _startDate = createdate() // = _dateFormatter.date(from: "01-12-2020 00:00:01")
    
    let _x = createdate()
    
    print("Create PDF")
}

func createdate() -> Date {
        return Date()
    }
```

What i want is an startdate based on an given year.
A string converted to an date.

When i do this in PlayGround it all works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: That response is in the debugger, right? So most likely there is no issue with your code, at least regarding _startDate. Try doing what it says, `po _startDate` in the console or add a print statement

Comment: When i do that i see:

po _startDate
▿ 2021-02-06 09:17:03 +0000
  - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 634295823.439398

Comment: Good! Then it isn't unavailable.

Comment: Unrelated but variable names with starting underscore character are *objective-c-ish* and unusual in Swift.

Comment: Somehow it seems to work now.

I don't understand how it happens.
Been working on this simple thing for a couple of day's now.

Comment: @vadian Is it better not to use an underscore ??

I use the underscore when creating an variable in an function.
To show it as an private variable.
Bit of old school programming.

Comment: It's not a question of better but as there are no  backing instance variables in Swift and private variables are clearly declared `private` there is no need.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.
Gonna change the writing style.